# What USB 3 AC1200 (or better) WiFi dongles are supported out-of-the-box on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: networking, drivers

Around here, the following are easily available:

- Asus USB-AC68
- D-Link DWA-185
- D-Link DWA-182
- D-Link DWA-192
- Linksys WUSB6400M
- Netgear A6150
- Netgear A6210
- TP-Link Archer T3U Plus
- TP-Link Archer T4U

I've tried the TP-Link Archer T3U Plus, there are multiple GitHub repositories, and none of them works well with current Ubuntu 20.04.

Is there a list of supported devices somewhere?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2397914

Comment: Brands/models are mostly irrelevant. What matters is the chipset.